# sockets - UDP Send data via internet

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I've made a simple chat application in c#.net that sends and receives data between 2 computers.

So, I used this method to send the data:

```
int port = 11000;    
private void send(string data, string ip)
{
    Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    IPEndPoint sending_end_point = null;
    byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
    try { sending_socket.SendTo(send_buffer, sending_end_point); }
    catch { }
}
```

And to receive I used this:

```
string receiveddata = "";
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(port);
    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    byte[] receive_byte_array;

    try
    {
        receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
        receiveddata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive_byte_array, 0, receive_byte_array.Length);
    }
    catch { }
    listener.Close();
}
```

This works without any problems between 2 computers on a LAN, but I would like to know (if possible) how to do the same thing over the Internet.

From what I've searched on the Internet, it seems that I have to use port-forwarding in order to do that, so I already did that, but I don't know what should I do know.

So my question is, how should I change this code (if I have to) so I could send and receive data (UDP) over the internet, assuming I have port-forwarded correctly already and assuming I know the external IPs of both routers?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine, as long as your (public) IP-address is correct and the ports are forwarded correctly on your router (meaning, forwarded to the correct private IP, on the correct protocol, in your case UDP).

You are aware that this is UDP though, so it's not reliable data transfer.